# Cocoa pods GLM Error

Tags: swift, cocoa

So today I've been trying to try out a new project using Swift, but I've arrived to an abrupt halt. I've been trying to run the VideoCore sample project found here: https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore/tree/823ec7cac50e5a0b4457bd06dd95a50dca88d9c0/sample/SampleBroadcaster-Swift.

So during the initial setup I had to navigate to the directory and run `pod install`. `pod install` executed without any errors, and say I need to close Xcode, and reopen the new workspace, which I did. When I try to go and run the app for debugging (as according to the documentation I can run it right after `pod install`'ing, I get an error that says `'type_half.inl' file not found`. A few screenshots are here to better explain/show: http://d.pr/i/14TqW, and http://d.pr/i/1aYSi.

I've tried reinstalling the pod multiple times, and I haven't been able to resolve this issue. Has anyone had a situation like this, or have any idea on how to get out of this blackhole?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved by downgrading CocoaPods to version 0.38.2. Here's what I did:

`gem install cocoapods -v 0.38.2
gem uninstall cocoapods -v 0.39.0`

And that fixed my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downgrading CocoaPods to version 0.38.2. This error can be resolved in other way as I have fixed recently on of my project.

STEP 1:- Search **Header Search Paths** under build setting on **GLM** target or target that uses GLM pod like in my project VideoCore cocoapods uses GLM

STEP 2:- make it recursive instead of non-recursive.

Build again error will be fixed.

NOTE:- if you update cocoapods that you have to redo the steps again. Also target will be in pod project.

Attached image for reference[image].